# butting pages together

Tags: single-word-requests

Is "butting" the term for tidying up loose pages to fit in one stack so none stick out?  What is a better term?

Picture a loose pile of pages, that you assemble to fit mostly together, then handle loosely and "pack" by dropping them through your hands to the desktop, narrow edges down, while handling the vertical edges to fit them all into one sheaf.  Maybe the stack has to be turned 90 deg and the action repeated on the long edges.

We all do it. But ;0 what do we call the action?

Comment: Thank you for asking. Some information will help us to give you the correct answer.
Please [edit] to add details of research you’ve done, especially solutions you’ve already rejected, and why.
Include the desired connotation, register (formality), part of speech, and context in which it is to be used, and provide the exact enclosing sentence or passage.
See: “[How much research is needed? – EL&U Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5039#5043)”.

Answer (score 2):

This is not specific to that particular action, but I would call it ***[straightening up](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/straighten%20up)*** the pages:

> : to make (something) organized or tidy : to put (something) in order
>   <sub>*from [m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/straighten%20up)*</sub>

(Normally I would consider "butting" to be aligning the pages in a row so that the end of one page fits completely against the start of the next page; see [butt, verb (2) definition 1](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/butt) for that meaning.)

Comment: or 'evening up'

Comment: So, "butting" it is.  The refinement is nothing but [ahem] turning the half-finished pack 90 deg and "butting" them again, and voila!

Comment: If I "butt" 10 normal 8.5 x 11 inch pages, I get a line 8.5 inches wide, 110 inches long, and 1 sheet thick; not a stack at all.  Then when I butt them the other way, I destroy my existing line and end up with one that's 93.5 inches wide, 11 inches long, and 1 sheet thck.

Answer (score 0):

I think the word *stack* works fine.

> Make sure you stack the pages evenly before you staple them. We need this to look professional.

Comment: I don't think OP means to ask about the action of stacking the pages, but rather the action of making the already made stack even, by gently bouncing off a hard surface with the guidance of one's hands, to even them out.

Comment: psosuna you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

[According to MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/butt), *butts* wouldn't work:   *to place end to end or side to side without overlapping*

You might use

***[Coordinate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coordinate)***

> transitive verb
>
> 1 : to put in the same order or rank
>
> 2 : to bring into a common action, movement, or condition : HARMONIZE

***He coordinated the sheets of paper so no corners or edges stuck out.***

Or just use *adjust* or *arrange*.

Answer (score 0):

You could say that you "registered" the pages, or put the pages "in register".

From Merriam-Webster:

> register (verb) -
>   registered; registering\ ˈre-​jə-​st(ə-​)riŋ  \
>
> transitive verb
>   2 : to make or adjust so as to correspond exactly
>
> intransitive verb
>   2a: to correspond exactly
>   2b: to be in correct alignment or register

Comment: This sounds very obscure to me. Looking at that MW definition, there are no example sentences with that meaning that I could find. Also, it sounds extremely strange, even given this as a new definition, to apply it to aligning physical objects. Can you find example sentences in the wild where this appears with this meaning?

Comment: Yep, it's not terribly common. I'm not sure what qualifies as the wild, but is often used in offset printing for aligning different colors (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printing_registration). Registration marks (https://www.boxcarpress.com/blog/crop-marks-and-registration-marks-a-printers-tool/) are a similar concept, but are used more generally for different processes not limited to applying pigment. Actually, that's the reason I thought "register" would be most fitting here; because it's most commonly used in aligning paper.

Comment: By 'in the wild' I mean not something you yourself or anybody made up as an example, but something said/written naturally. So it sounds like this is a 'correct' answer, but only in very rare, technical circumstances.

Comment: @Mitch, I don't understand your objection. The word "register" literally meets the OPs criteria.

Comment: Registration is far more exacting and misses the informality of the simple handling process I described in some detail at the start.  Butting works for the purpose named: "I butted the pile of papers"...it would not suffice for 3-color offset printing.

Answer (score 0):

Consider  **to even up**  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/65254?rskey=rJ4DlZ&result=5&isAdvanced=false#eid)

> 1. transitive. To make (something) even or equal; to balance;

As in: Boys' Life - Oct 1991 [google books](https://books.google.com/books?id=hPgDAAAAMBAJ&lpg=PA64&dq=%22even%20up%20the%20pages%22&pg=PA65#v=onepage&q=%22even%20up%20the%20pages%22&f=falsehttps://)

> **Even up** the pages, and clamp the book together with binder clips, or
>   weigh down the front edge to keep the pages from moving.

Comment: Thanks.  It's adequately descriptive imo, though it misses the idea of dropping the partly-formed pile through one's hands.

Answer (score -1):

A machine which does this is a "paper jogger".

[image: https://www.amazon.com/Lassco-LJ-2-Office-Paper-Jogger/dp/B003BWQFLM]

Comment: I'll keep "jogging" in mind with "evening" if I forget "butting" and it's not too late ;)